# Is there a Linear Algebra textbook with comprehensive material on both the applied and theoretical aspects of the subject?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, proof-writing, applications

I am looking for a linear algebra book, or series of books, that can aid me in learning the theoretical (proof-based) mathematical side, along with the applied (physics in my situation) based side. Thank you.

Some of the books I have been looking at are those by authors: Axler, Triel, Lay, Lang, Strang, Friedman, Hoffman, Halmos

Comment: If you are interested in applications, then none of the books you mention is good. Moreover I do not know any good (in your sense) book written in English.

Comment: I don't know of any mathematics text that deal both with elementary linear algebra that meaningfully tackle the usage of linear algebra in physics; traditionally, these topics are taught separately rather than in tandem. That said, I do recall that Friedberg Insel Spence has an interesting aside about relativity.